# Cannot drop index from Azure database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We got the issue that we cannot drop the index in azure database (the database is on Elastic pool) by running the below in SSMS:

```
DROP INDEX [nci_wi_FactInvoiceDetail_145BA2082F925FB3C62800F00A3ECF41] 
ON [SPENDBY].[FactInvoiceDetail]
```

We got timeout exception.

This index was created automatically using Automatic Tuning option from Azure Portal before this option was turned off on server level:

[image]

Any ideas for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you are getting a timeout since the index is in use.

You could try disabling the index before you delete it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's correct, we found there is running query on the background running for a long time